# Thinking-Sphinx-Raspell configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am using rails 2.3.4 and sphinx 1.4.4 and raspell 1.0.0. Now I would like to 
add fuzzy match in sphinx search, so I added in my `config/environment.rb` file I added the following lines:

```
config = ThinkingSphinx::Configuration.instance

config.raspell.dictionary             = 'en'

config.raspell.suggestion_mode        = :badspellers
```

Ref - https://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx-raspell

while starting my server it throws the error like this

```
 undefined method `raspell' for 
 #<ThinkingSphinx::Configuration:0xb63d7f8c> (NoMethodError)
```

Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem because of the gem versions. 
I modified gem versions this issue is fixed now.

Here the Gems and its versions:

**Thinking sphinx - 1.3.17**

**Active Record - 2.3.5**

**After Commit - 1.0.10**

**Riddle - 1.0.10**

**Thinking sphinx Raspell - 1.1.1**

**Raspell -1.3**

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you shift that configuration to an initialiser? And do you have it currently at the top or the bottom of config/environment.rb? It should be at the bottom, outside of Rails' own configuration block (gems aren't loaded until the block is processed).

Comment: Thanks for your reply..
I shift that configuration to initializer. Then run the same it produces the same error...